# how to prevent user to "GO BACK" after login in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

After user login and click go back. it will back to the login page again.

Comment: you can add a condition in your login page if a user already login then redirect to home page.

Comment: Can you clarify that? To which page should he not "go back"?

Comment: Alright. all i want is , when a user has a session , user will not go back to login form. In my case , when a user was login and click go back , it is go back in my login form

Answer (score 0):

It **sounds** like what you're asking for is how you can prevent a user from being able to navigate back through their history to view the unauthenticated login page if they're already logged in. Unfortunately, you **can't**.

Sure, you can add things such as automatic redirections on the login page based on the user's `$_SESSON`, but this session will not exist when the page is first visited by the user. Adding cache control headers that force the user to reload the content won't work either, and these are only applied when a user visits a particular URL, not when they click the back button in their browser.

If the user hits back on their browser, and **then** hits **refresh**, they will load the page again (along with any redirection logic), but you cannot prevent them from seeing the login page on the initial press of their back button. Even if you were to add multiple redirection steps during the login process, they would still be able to manually navigate back in time to the unauthenticated login page.